# navigate.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer()) not working in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

> On click of a cross button the drawer should be closed, that is the
>   thing I am trying. I have passed down the props inside component but
>   giving error that  navigate.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer()) is
>   undefined.
>
> I am providing My code
>
> SideMenu.js which the layout of drawer menu. From here I am passing
>   props to drawerheader.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import DrawerHeader from './DrawerHeader';
import DrawerMenu from './DrawerMenu';
import { StackNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';
class SideMenuLayout extends Component {
    state = {
        menuNames:[{
            id:'0',
            name:'My Profile',
            link:''
        },{
            id:'1',
            name:'Place Order',
            link:''
        },{
            id:'2',
            name:'Order History',
            link:'OrderHistory'
        },{
            id:'3',
            name:'Payment',
            link:''
        },{
            id:'4',
            name:'Recharge',
            link:''
        },{
            id:'5',
            name:'Help',
            link:''
        },{
            id:'6',
            name:'Logout',
            link:''
        }]
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
               <DrawerHeader navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
               <DrawerMenu 
                    navigation={this.props.navigation} 
                    menuItems={this.state} 
                    style={{ marginTop: 106/3}}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default SideMenuLayout;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    }
});
```

> **Drawer Header code goes here. Here I am trying to close the navigation drawer.**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet,Image,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { DrawerActions, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
const DrawerHeader = (props)=> {

    const { navigate } = props.navigation;
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d61822',width:DRAWER_CONTAINER_WIDTH/3,height:DRAWER_CONTAINER_HEIGHT/3  }}>
                <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                    <View style={{ marginLeft:20, backgroundColor:'#d61822',height:40 }}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:28,fontStyle:'italic',color:'#ffff',fontWeight:'bold'}}>
                            Prabhuji Online
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ marginLeft:35,backgroundColor:'#d61822',width: 50, height: 40,paddingRight:10,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigate.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'#ffff',}}>
                            <FontAwesome 
                                style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end'}} 
                                name="times" 
                                size={18} 
                                color="#ffffff" 
                            />
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.fakeContainer}>

                </View>
                <View style={{
                        position:'absolute',
                        top: 170/3,
                        marginLeft:20,
                        width:220/3,
                        height:220/3,
                        backgroundColor:'#fffcf9',
                        borderRadius:(220/3)/2,
                        justifyContent:'center',
                        alignContent:'center',
                        alignItems:'center',
                        shadowColor: "#000",
                        shadowOffset: {
                            width: 0,
                            height: 5,
                        },
                        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
                        shadowRadius: 6.27,
                        elevation: 7,
                    }}>
                        <Image
                        tintColor='red'
                         style={{
                            width: 111/3,
                            height: 111/3,
                        }} 
                        source={require('../../../assets/place_order.png')}/>
                </View>
            </View>

        );
    }
export default DrawerHeader;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    titleContainer:{
        backgroundColor: '#d61822',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        height:TITLE_CONTAINER_HEIGHT/3,
        marginTop: 50/3,
    },
    fakeContainer:{
        position:'relative',
        height:FAKE_CONTAINER_HEIGHT/3,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        //backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    }
});
```

> Can any one please tell me what is going wrong here?
>   I have also tried navigate.closeDrawer(). But same error is giving.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `navigate` call, you need to dispatch the action like this: `this.props.navigation.dispatch(*your action here*)`, as described in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#dispatch-send-an-action-to-the-router

Comment: but I don't need to close the drawer, not sending actions to the router. can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're saying and what you want to achieve..?